# Separating Read / Write Responsibilities of a DB

Tags: java, programming-practices, object-oriented-design

We're working on a reporting system which has a clear write and a read path. For example writes will only happen after consuming events from a queue and reads will only happen when serving requests from an API. The responsibilities won't likely mix, i.e. the service writing to the DB won't use the queries used by the API and vice versa.

The code is really long (cause java) and could be confusing to a new person. I was thinking of separating the DB into two classes, ReportingIngestDBClient vs ReportingReadDBClient not married to the names.

I was wondering:

- 1) Has anyone followed this pattern? Did it make things more or less clear? If so what names did you use?
- 2) If you didn't follow the pattern of creating 2 separate objects to handle different queries, do you have a strong opinion against it and why?

Comment: you might be interested [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)

Comment: Thanks @Laiv Seems like the warning here is CQRS is a double edge sword.

Comment: No pun intended.

Comment: @devkaoru I guess that anything could be a double edge sword if used/implemented unwisely. I just wanted you know that there's an architectural style that reflects what you are trying to do. I would read a bit more about CQRS. Greg Young has wrote several post about CQRS. Just wanted you had  a reference.

Comment: yep yep, sorry I didn't mean to discount the technique, appreciate the reference!

Comment: What's the chance of the reads, at some point in the future, talking to completely different datasource than the writes?

Comment: @user949300 not likely in foreseeable future, but now that i said it'll be next month =P

Answer (score 2):

As Laiv put in his comment, you should look at CQRS design pattern. And let me expand on it here.

CQRS stands for Command Query Responsibility Segregation. The fundamental idea is to divide your data access code into two sharply separated categories:

**Queries**: Return a result and do not change the observable state of the system (are free of side effects).

**Commands**: Change the state of a system but do not return a value.

Here are a few articles to get you started on CQRS design pattern:

1. Martin Fowler - [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)
2. Greg Young - [CQRS, Task Based UIs, Event Sourcing agh!](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/02/16/cqrs-task-based-uis-event-sourcing-agh/)
3. Udi Dahan - [Clarified CQRS](http://udidahan.com/2009/12/09/clarified-cqrs/)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you add structure you also reduce flexibility so in general you should only have as much structure as you really need. I would argue that this separation is not really necessary, and more flexibility would be better.

I would also look at it from this perspective. One purpose of encapsulation is to simplify the code by isolating knowledge (business logic) to one part of the system. If you have separate read and write databases, you should minimize the number of places in your software that needs to know this.

It seems like a natural fit for the dual database design to be understood by the data access layer, but if you split the data access into two classes then many other parts of your system need to be aware of this design, because they have to decide which of the two data layers they should call based on whether the database gets updated or not. For the rest of the application to know if the database gets updated means having a detailed knowledge of exactly how the database works - which is a kind of coupling.

In summary, if you create two classes then consumers of those classes need to understand enough about the database design to make the correct choice about which one to use, and this creates coupling between the database design and the consumers of the data layer. The data layer is supposed to hide these details from these consumers.